# Python Crawler | "URL" Parameter to access from application/ld+json

Tags: python

I would like to access the "Url" parameter. Can someone help me with this?

i get the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import requests
url1 ="https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/790"
r = requests.get(url1)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

liste = doc.find_all("script",type='application/ld+json')
print(liste)

liste["url"]

[<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":0,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-431740032/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441993023/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441800245/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441780586/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441778309/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":5,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441775999/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":6,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-441774156/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":7,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-440113662/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":8,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-440036742/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":9,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-438250382/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":10,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-435658668/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":11,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-790-l-435158113/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":12,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-434579444/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":13,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-433046618/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":14,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-modell-2020-433003928/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":15,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-431610682/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":16,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-topzustand-431583298/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":17,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-damenfahrzeug-40-mm-originaltieferlegung-430439758/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":18,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-430360674/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":19,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-430210765/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":20,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-430088585/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":21,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-s-nur-600km-neu-428798689/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":22,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-441816402/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":23,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-790r-427780213/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":24,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-427659637/"}],"numberOfItems":30,"name":"KTM 790 Motorrad gebraucht oder neu kaufen - willhaben","description":"KTM 790 Motorrad günstig kaufen. Aktuell 30 KTM 790 Motorräder vom Händler oder Privat in deiner Nähe und in ganz Österreich."}</script>, <script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","@id":"#breadcrumbs","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"name":"Startseite","item":{"@type":"Thing","id":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad","url":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"name":"Auto & Motor","item":{"@type":"Thing","id":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/","url":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"name":"Motorräder und Quads","item":{"@type":"Thing","id":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/","url":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"name":"KTM","item":{"@type":"Thing","id":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/","url":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":5,"name":"790","item":{"@type":"Thing","id":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/790/","url":"https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/790/"}}]}</script>]
```

---

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c95d3da62183> in <module>
      3 
      4 
----> 5 liste["url"]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `liste` has multiple `url`s, which one do you expect?

Comment: Please clarify what is unclear to you. As the errors says, you are working with a list which only has integer keys, not string keys – it has no single ``url`` parameter.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia 
i want to output all urls

Comment: @MisterMiyagi
How can I convert the list into string keys so that I can filter out the urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple `JOSN` objects in that `script` tag. You have to extract those first and then dump them to a `JSON` again.

Here's how:

```
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/790"
doc = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url1).text, "html.parser")

liste = doc.find_all("script", type='application/ld+json')
json_objects = [
    json.loads(re.search(r">(.*)<", str(s), re.S).group(1)) for s in liste
]

print(json_objects[0]["itemListElement"][0]["url"])
```

Output:

```
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-431740032/
```

To list all of them, just use this:

```
for item in json_objects[0]["itemListElement"]:
    print(item["url"])
```

Output:

```
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-431740032/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441993023/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441800245/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441780586/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441778309/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-441775999/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-441774156/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-440113662/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-440036742/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-438250382/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-435658668/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-790-l-435158113/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-434579444/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-433046618/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-modell-2020-433003928/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-431610682/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-topzustand-431583298/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-damenfahrzeug-40-mm-originaltieferlegung-430439758/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-430360674/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-duke-430210765/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-r-430088585/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-s-nur-600km-neu-428798689/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-441816402/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-adventure-790r-427780213/
/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-427659637/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[i.next for i in liste]
b=json.loads(a[0])['itemListElement']
c=json.loads(a[1])['itemListElement']
[i['url'] for i in b]
[i['item']['url'] for i in c]
```

`.next` calls the next tag

`liste` has two items each having different structure